# How to appropiately create a matrix with intersection count between multiple list in python

Tags: python, nlp

Good day,

As trying to learn NLP, I was making an Exploratory Data Analysis.
After some data cleaning, I found myself needing to compare several list which contain the most used words in different topics. For that, I need to display a matrix showing the number of elements that every combination of 2 of those list have in common.

For instance, let´s say that I have the following 3 list of 4 elements, where every element of a list must be distinct:

a = ['rabbit', 'fox', 'cat', 'dog']

b = ['snake', 'tiger', 'fox', 'cat']

c = ['lion', 'tiger', 'fox', 'cow']

And I want to obtain a 3x3 matrix like this one:

4   2    1

2   4    2

1   2    4

Ie, the element (1,2) is equal to the element (2,1), being 2, because the list a and b have 2 words in common ('fox' and 'cat').
Then, the matrix will be symmetric and the elements within the diagonal must be the lenght of the vector (4).

My goal is trying to visualize how similar are those different topics based on the amount of top 4 most used words in common when people speak about them.

I think that something like len(set(a).intersection(b)) could be an option.
Since I have more topics in my actual dataset, and the matrix will be 50*50 (and with the top 10 most used words for each category), I was considering if maybe there is a more efficient way to do it than iterating through the lists and calculating the length of the set intersection.

I also think that there must be a better implementation of this. I know that rewritting this on numpy must be the first step for making it more optimal. But aside from that, I was supposing this kind of need will be recurrent and probably already implemented on pandas, nltk, etc. However, I am not being able to find anything related. I am also concerned about not being considering a better visualization technique for this goal.

Thanks in advance and wish you a great day!

Comment: One optimisation you can use is to avoid iterating over all the pairs - the matrix is symmetrical over diagnal, so you can calculate only one half of it and mirror the results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.